# Deprecated Functionality: Creation of dynamic property $_coreRegistry is deprecated

Tags: exception, magento2.4.6, deprecated, php8, php8.2

I am having this issue with magento 2.4.6 custom module and php8.2

This code:

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate
    ) {
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        $this->_localeDate = $localeDate;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
```

line with

```
$this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
```

Throw error:

```
Exception #0 (Exception): Deprecated Functionality: Creation of dynamic property \Helper\Data::$_coreRegistry is deprecated in app/code/MyFolder/Helper/Data.php on line 47
```

I have no clue what to change and fix this

Any help please?

Comment: Hi @G. G. If my answer helps you resolve your issue, please mark it as accepted. That indicates your issue is solved and helps others with the same issue find the verified answer easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Deprecated Functionality: Creation of dynamic property \Helper\Data::$_coreRegistry is deprecated

You must declare this property (`$_coreRegistry`) in your class.
To do this, add the following code above the `__construct` method:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
 */
private $_coreRegistry;
```

There is another solution is changing this property (`$_coreRegistry`) in your class to match the $argument in the `__construct` method, which is `$registry`. To do this, replace all text `_coreRegistry` with `registry`.

Here, I highly recommend using the second solution as it leverages the constructor property promotion (new feature) in PHP 8. To view a demonstration of this feature, you can watch the following video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I960JDkmXY0

Comment: Thanks! It's work for me!

Comment: @qɐʇǝɥɐW My pleasure.